# Problems with selection and highlighting in ClistCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I found some problem.

I have class extended from CListCtrl. When I make double click on row I selected it. Everything good, but if I sort some column I have problem!

For example:
I have some row in second position. I selected it and sort column, highlighting is left on second position but my item has moved to 4th row (and selection moved to 4th row)

I have bad feeling that it could be some bug:(

Did somebody see problem like this?

PS: I'm not sure that I have to provide some code, because guess it's ok, but if needs it I will post it

Thank you very much and sorry for my English)

Comment: Sounds like you've somehow separated selection from highlighting in your extending class. I think you should add the code of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen this problem with owner data list views (LVS_OWNERDATA) so I'm guessing this is the case here. AFIK there are two possible solutions. The first is to store the selection state yourself and then use LVM_SETCALLBACKMASK to let the control know that you will provide the selection state. You will also have to respond to mouse clicks and update your data array. The other solution is to store a list of selected items before sorting, deselect all items, do the sorting and then finally restore the selection using the stored list.

Comment: hi Abraxas!
But this problem exists only on Windows 8

Comment: If you are not implementing a virtual list view (without the LVS_OWNERDATA style) then I’m sorry I have no idea what the problem is. However, If you are implementing a virtual list view (with the LVS_OWNERDATA style) then this problem exists for ALL versions of Windows.